# angular request busy interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

## UPDATE

I think I solved it myself. Check [my interceptor that I posted as a solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33494335/1295183).

## ORIGINAL

I was wondering if it would be possible to write an http interceptor that can let the caller know how the request is doing.

Right now, when I want to call my backend, I wrap an $http call in a wrapper that sets attributes on an object I pass it:

```
publ.wrap = function(f, ctrl){

    ctrl.busy   = true;
    ctrl.error  = false;

    return f()

    .then(function(res){

        ctrl.busy   = false;
        ctrl.result = res;

        return res;

    }).catch(function(err){

        ctrl.busy   = false;
        ctrl.error  = err;
        ctrl.result = undefined;

    })

};



publ.login    = function(args, ctrl){

    publ.wrap(function(){

        return $http.post('http://localhost:3001/authenticate', {
            username : args.username,
            password : args.password
        }).then(function(jwt){

            $cookies.put('token', jwt);
        })
    }, ctrl);
};
```

In this case, I call `login(authArgs, $scope.loginCtrl)` in my login page controller. Then I use `loginCtrl.busy`, `loginCtrl.result` & `loginCtrl.error` in my login template.

I pretty much want every call I make to the backend to set these attributes and make them available to the views that initiate the request.

Using a wrapper function like this gets the job done, but I'm wondering if it can be done using an interceptor? It feels to me like that would provide a much cleaner request flow that doesn't require me to explicitly wrap all of my backend calls in my services.

Now I read up on httpInterceptors, and can't seem to find a way to have them set attributes on a user-provided object. The closes thing I found was [this article](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/) that has an example ( Timestamp Marker (request and response interceptors) ) where they add attributes to the config object in both the `request` and `response` interceptor stages.They don't show how to access the config object inside the `responseError` stage or in the caller controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the interceptor working. Apparently we CAN access the config file in all interceptor phases:

```
/******************************************
    SETUP BUSY/ERROR/DATA HTTP INTERCEPTOR
*******************************************/
.config(function($httpProvider){

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
      return {

        request  : function(config) {

            if(config.ctrl){
                config.ctrl.busy   = true;
                config.ctrl.error  = false;
                config.ctrl.data   = undefined;
            }

            return config;
        },
        response : function(response) {

            if(response.config && response.config.ctrl){
                response.config.ctrl.busy = false;
                response.config.ctrl.data = response.data;
            }

            return response;
        },

        responseError : function(response){

            // note: maybe use a different error message for different kinds of responses?
            var error = response.status + " "+response.statusText+" - "+response.data;

            if(response.config && response.config.ctrl){
                response.config.ctrl.busy = false;
                response.config.ctrl.error = error;
            }

            return $q.reject(error);
        }
      };
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular events to handle stuff like this- for example:

```
    .controller('parentCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('loading',function(e,_statusObj.loading) {
            $scope.loading = _statusObj.loading;
            if(!!_statusObj.msg) {
                alert(_statusObj.msg);
            }
        });
    })
    .controller('childCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.myAjaxCall = function(_url,_data) {
            $scope.$emit('loading',{ loading: true});
            $http.post(_url,_data).success(function(_response) {
                $scope.$emit('loading',{ loading: false });
            })
            .error(function(_error) {
                $scope.$emit('loading',{
                    loading : false,
                    msg     : _error.message
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this won't work properly when multiple requests are sent at the same time. The `loading` event will be sent for all, and there won't be a way to differentiate between them. Also, the code is messier than I'd like.